# Bootstrap glyphicon in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a trouble using [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/) in PHP. Here is the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''glyphicon-ok'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

```
<i class="glyphicon
<?php 
echo $output 'glyphicon-ok';?> "></i>
```

Comment: You need a dot (.) between $output and 'glyphicon-ok'.

Comment: Thankyou for the answers but its only echoing   glyphicon-ok';?>

Comment: `$output` is empty then.

Comment: @Forien $output .=  '<tr>' .'<td>'.$fname.' '.$lname.'
     <input type="checkbox" style="position:absolute; right: 1000px;">'.'</tr>' . '</td>';

Comment: @maiko you want to output html tags **within** `class` attribute? I wouldn't do that...

Comment: is it not possible? sorry im just new in php just gathering codes from resources

Comment: It's not `php` thing. It's about `HTML` syntax, which doesn't allow tags (or more precisely `nodes`) within attributes' values.

Answer (score 1):

So far I can only guess, but probably you wanted something like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <?= $output ?>
```

If doesn't work due to `<?=` tag, change then to `<?php echo $output ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing concatenation operator `.(dot)`  after `echo $output`.

```
<i class="glyphicon <?php echo $output.'glyphicon-ok';?> "></i>
                                     ^^^^
```

OR might be you want this

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i><?php echo $output;?>
```

Comment: Thankyou but its only echoing glyphicon-ok';?>

Comment: What is in `$output` ? Have you check?

Comment: $output .=  '<tr>' .'<td>'.$fname.' '.$lname.'
<input type="checkbox" style="position:absolute; right: 1000px;">'.'</tr>' . '</td>';

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you say. but here's the thing when i only put <?php echo $output; ?> without the glyphicons the program works.

Comment: @Sadikhasan I'm not sure if bootstrap glyphicons work well when there is text within node.

Comment: thankyou for the help @Sadikhasan and forien maybe I'll just change the design of the program :-)